# Windows Vista wont recognize SSD drive

Tags: windows, windows-vista, ssd

I just bought an SSD drive for my Vista (32bit) box (120GB OCZ Agility 3). Unfortunately windows vista won't display it in the my computer window, and generally wont let me work on it. However, the bios recognizes the SSD drive correctly, and when I go on the windows device manager the drive is there as well. I can see the device properties.

On the volumes, when I click on populate, I have: 
Disk: Disk1
Type: Uknown
Status: not initialized
Partition style: not avaiable
Unallocated space: 0MB
Reserved space: 0MB

Any ideas what could be wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right click on the drive in disk Management and pick initialize.  One that is complete, you will be able to create partitions.

Comment: Ah disk management tool. Did not even think about it. Thanks, that worked!